# Django admin: Using messages.error still results in confirmation being shown

Tags: django, django-admin, django-messages

I've overridden my save_model() function to wrap the obj.save() call in a try/catch.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    from concurrency.exceptions import RecordModifiedError
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    try: 

        obj.save()
        # some other stuff

    except RecordModifiedError:
        messages.error(request, "[!] Record modified. Please try again.")
        #self.message_user(request, "[!] Record modified. Please try again.", level="error")
```

Catching the RecordModifiedError is working, and the data is not saved. However, the confirmation message that appears on a successful save is still showing, as is the error. I have two contradictory messages being shown!

I'm wondering how to prevent the success message from being displayed. Thanks!

EDIT: also tried the `self.message_user()` function, but it didn't block the success message either.

Comment: well?? Did you find the solution for it? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

doesnot it have to be in this way?

```
try: 

    obj.save()
    messages.error(request, "[!] Record modified.")

except RecordModifiedError:
    messages.error(request, "[!] Record NOT modified. Please try again.")
```

Comment: This didn't change the behaviour. Now I see two success messages when I save successfully. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
storage.used = True
messages.error(request, "[!] Record modified. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same issue by overwriting the `message_user` function.  I set a flag if there was an error. If the flag is set, then have `message_user` return, if not set then call the base class `message_user` using the `super` function.